# How can I dedicate threads to run Sidekiq jobs with Puma or Raptor server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, puma

Let's say my process will run 3 workers, and I want to dedicate 1 of them to process web requests, and 2 to handle Sidekiq background jobs, each process potentially being multi-threaded. Is there an easy or best-practices way to handle this? I've tried a few different configurations, but they either give me an error, or just don't process the jobs at all.

I'm using Rails 4 and ActiveJob, but I don't think those points are relevant.

Comment: I feel like your question is not clear.  You want your app to run three processes, one of which is a puma/raptor server and two of which sidekiq workers?  Have you looked at foreman?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to take care of sidekiq worker scheduling from you rails application. Sidekiq runs a separate process with the whole rails environment for managing the background workers. Each Worker is a separate Thread, backed by the Celluloid Actor framework. So for your setup you just do the following:

```bash
# start a single puma web server process with min 4 and max 16 Threads
$ bundle exec puma -t 4:16  

# start a single multithreaded sidekiq process,    
# with councurrency settings defined in sidekiq.yml
$ bundle exec sidekiq --pidfile tmp/pids/sidekiq_1.pid 

# start another sidekiq process (if really necessary)
$ bundle exec sidekiq --pidfile tmp/pids/sidekiq_2.pid
```